Swish API Payout Request: Error 'PA01: Parameter is not correct'
I'm trying to integrate the Swish API for a payout request using Node.js and Express. Despite following the documentation closely, I keep encountering the error with 401 unauthorized error:
{
  "errorCode": "PA01",
  "errorMessage": "Parameter is not correct.",
  "additionalInformation": null
}

Here is my current code:
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));
const forge = require('node-forge');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const basePath = '/Users/xx/downloads/mss_test_2.0/Getswish_Test_Certificates/';

const authCertPath = path.join(basePath, 'Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1234679304.p12');
const signingCertPath = path.join(basePath, 'Swish_Merchant_TestSigningCertificate_1234679304.p12');
const caCertPath = path.join(basePath, 'Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem');

const passphrase = 'swish'; // Assuming this is the passphrase for both certificates

const getCertAndKeyFromP12 = (p12Path, passphrase) => {
    const p12Content = fs.readFileSync(p12Path, 'binary');
    const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Content);
    const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, passphrase);
    const keyObj = p12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag })[forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];
    const certObj = p12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag })[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
    const key = forge.pki.privateKeyToPem(keyObj.key);
    const cert = forge.pki.certificateToPem(certObj.cert);
    return { cert, key };
};

const getCertificateSerialNumber = (certPath, passphrase) => {
    const certContent = fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'binary');
    const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(certContent);
    const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, passphrase);
    const certObj = p12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag })[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
    const cert = forge.pki.certificateToPem(certObj.cert);
    const serialNumber = certObj.cert.serialNumber.toUpperCase();
    console.log(`Extracted Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
    return serialNumber;
};

const getHashedPayload = (payload) => {
    return crypto.createHash('sha512').update(payload).digest();
};

const getCertificateSignature = (hash, privateKey) => {
    const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA512');
    sign.update(hash);
    sign.end();
    return sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
};

app.post('/create-payout', (req, res) => {
    const { cert, key: signingPrivateKey } = getCertAndKeyFromP12(signingCertPath, passphrase);

    const payload = {
        amount: parseFloat(req.body.amount,2).toString(),
        currency: 'SEK',
        instructionDate: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: req.body.message,
        payeeAlias: '0728648607',
        payeeSSN: '196702234292',
        payerAlias: '1234679304',
        payerPaymentReference: 'mockedPayerPaymentReference',
        payoutInstructionUUID: '822735C159A944DBB2B3546717BC919F',
        payoutType: 'PAYOUT',
        signingCertificateSerialNumber: getCertificateSerialNumber(signingCertPath, passphrase)
    };

    const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
    const payloadHash = getHashedPayload(payloadString);
    const signature = getCertificateSignature(payloadHash, signingPrivateKey);

    const requestBody = {
        payload,
        signature,
        callbackUrl: 'https://xxxx.ngrok-free.app/swishcallback'
    };
console.log(JSON.stringify(requestBody))
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        agent: new https.Agent({
            pfx: fs.readFileSync(authCertPath),
            passphrase: passphrase,
            ca: fs.readFileSync(caCertPath)
        })
    };

    fetch('https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/payouts', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error: error.message }));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000');
});





Request body:
{
  "amount": 100.00,
  "message": "example message"
}

I followed the Swish API documentation for creating a payout request using Node.js and Express. I ensured that the payload is correctly formatted and generated a signature using the required cryptographic methods. I included the necessary certificates and keys in the request setup.
I'm looking for insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Swish API docs:
https://developer.swish.nu/documentation/environments
https://developer.swish.nu/api/mss/v1#create-payout-request

formatted for pA01 issue
const express = require('express');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const https = require('https');
    const path = require('path');
    const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));
    const forge = require('node-forge');
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    
    const basePath = '/Users/xx/downloads/mss_test_2.0/Getswish_Test_Certificates/';
    
    const authCertPath = path.join(basePath, 'Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1234679304.p12');
    const signingCertPath = path.join(basePath, 'Swish_Merchant_TestSigningCertificate_1234679304.p12');
    const caCertPath = path.join(basePath, 'Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem');
    
    const passphrase = 'swish'; // Assuming this is the passphrase for both certificates
    
    const getCertAndKeyFromP12 = (p12Path, passphrase) => {
        const p12Content = fs.readFileSync(p12Path, 'binary');
        const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Content);
        const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, passphrase);
        const keyObj = p12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag })[forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];
        const certObj = p12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag })[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
        const key = forge.pki.privateKeyToPem(keyObj.key);
        const cert = forge.pki.certificateToPem(certObj.cert);
        return { cert, key };
    };
    
    const getCertificateSerialNumber = (certPath, passphrase) => {
        const certContent = fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'binary');
        const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(certContent);
        const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, passphrase);
        const certObj = p12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag })[forge.pki.oids.certBag][0];
        const serialNumber = certObj.cert.serialNumber.toUpperCase();
        console.log(`Extracted Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
        return serialNumber;
    };
    
    const getHashedPayload = (payload) => {
        return crypto.createHash('sha512').update(payload).digest();
    };
    
    const getCertificateSignature = (hash, privateKey) => {
        const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA512');
        sign.update(hash);
        sign.end();
        return sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
    };
    
    app.post('/create-payout', (req, res) => {
        const { cert, key: signingPrivateKey } = getCertAndKeyFromP12(signingCertPath, passphrase);
    
        // Create the payload
        const payload = {
            amount: parseFloat(req.body.amount).toFixed(2), // Ensure amount is formatted correctly
            currency: 'SEK',
            instructionDate: new Date().toISOString().replace(/\.\d+Z$/, 'Z'), // Ensure correct format
            payeeAlias: '0728648607',
            payeeSSN: '196702234292',
            payerAlias: '1234679304',
            payerPaymentReference: 'mockedPayerPaymentReference',
            payoutInstructionUUID: '822735C159A944DBB2B3546717BC919F',
            payoutType: 'PAYOUT',
            signingCertificateSerialNumber: getCertificateSerialNumber(signingCertPath, passphrase)
        };
    
        // Add message field if provided and valid
        if (req.body.message && req.body.message.length <= 50) {
            payload.message = req.body.message;
        }
    
        const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
        const payloadHash = getHashedPayload(payloadString);
        const signature = getCertificateSignature(payloadHash, signingPrivateKey);
    
        const requestBody = {
            payload,
            signature,
            callbackUrl: 'https://xxxx.ngrok-free.app/swishcallback'
        };
    
        console.log('Request Body:', JSON.stringify(requestBody));
    
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
            agent: new https.Agent({
                pfx: fs.readFileSync(authCertPath),
                passphrase: passphrase,
                ca: fs.readFileSync(caCertPath)
            })
        };
    
        fetch('https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/payouts', requestOptions)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    // Handle non-2xx responses
                    console.log('Error Response:', response.statusText);
                    return response.json().then(errorData => {
                        throw new Error(`Swish API error: ${errorData.errorCode} - ${errorData.errorMessage}`);
                    });
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('API Response:', data);
                res.json(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Request Error:', error.message);
                res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
            });
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000');
    });


What do you mean by "formatted for pA01 issue" ?

It was the certificates for me. I was using only singing certificates but not passing the correct auth certificate

In my case I was supplying swish with a UUID4 as such
16e8aff8-977f-42d0-bd16-bf39d3b9b3c4

It turns out you need to ditch the dashes and convert letters to uppercase
16E8AFF8977F42D0BD16BF39D3B9B3C4

So, to create a payment request:
const paymentReference = getuuid().toUpperCase().replaceAll ('-', '');

const swishUrl = `https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v2/paymentrequests/${paymentReference}`

